# Undeterministic unwanted additional triangles on Android OpenGL ES rendering under SDL

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, sdl

I'm developing simple game (Kula world clone) for mobile devices (currently on android devices).
The problem is that sometimes I get additional (no missing) triangles on random models in game, all in undeterministic fashion (triangles appears on random models on random places between application runs). Also it is sometimes almost unnoticeable on my HTC phone, but always massive on my Nexus 7 tablet.

I am using OpenGL ES 2 and SDL2. Application is written in C++ for code portability.

I was thinking about some buggy model loading code, but I think that it would be deterministic and there would be also some missing triangles not only additional. But the fact that it's non-deterministic and device depended leads me that it is more likely some bug in rendering.

Here are some screenshots:

From my HTC Desire C:

[image]

and

[image]

Much worse on my Nexus 7:

[image]

Vertex shader source:

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 tc;
uniform mat4 mvp; 
varying vec2 coord; 
varying vec3 color;
void main() { gl_Position = mvp*vec4(position,1); coord = tc; }
```

and model drawing code:

```
void Entity::draw(GLuint HpositionAttrib, GLuint HtcAttrib, GLuint HtextureUniform, GLuint HmvpUniform,     glm::mat4 tmvp)
{
    glUniformMatrix4fv(HmvpUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(localTransforms(tmvp)));
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glUniform1i(HtextureUniform, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(HpositionAttrib);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(HtcAttrib);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glVertexAttribPointer(HpositionAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLubyte *)NULL + offsetof(vertex, position));
    glVertexAttribPointer(HtcAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLubyte *)NULL + offsetof(vertex, uvmap));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBufferObject);
#ifdef DEBUG
    SDL_Log("buffer: %d vertex: %d elements: %d\n",VBOSize, sizeof(GLushort), VBOSize/sizeof(GLushort));
#endif
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, VBOSize/sizeof(unsigned short), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, VBOSize/sizeof(GLushort), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(HpositionAttrib);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(HtcAttrib);
}
```

//Edit: I have addresed issues metioned by Andon M. Coleman

And there is definition of VBOSize:
It is instance variable declared:

```
    size_t VBOSize, EBOSize;
```

and is initialized as follows:

```
    VBOSize(vertices.size()*sizeof(vertex)), EBOSize(indexes.size()*sizeof(GLushort))
```

Where vertices is:

```
    std::vector<vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<GLushort> indexes;
```

These vectors are initialised from external file.

And I am using it like this:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOSize, &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenBuffers(1, &elementBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBOSize, &indexes[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: I don't know if it's causing the artefacts, but I notice you pass 3 as the number of components to `glVertexAttribPointer` for your `tc` attribute. It's declared as a vec2 in your shader. How is it declared in your `vertex` struct?

Comment: @GuyRT keep in mind that this is Java and there is no such thing as `struct` in Java.

Comment: @Vallentin The question is tagged as "C++", so I think this is native code.

Comment: @GuyRT I apologize, didn't read the C++ tag only saw the Android tag, and yea Android uses Java, but sorry.

Comment: it is defined as follows: `typedef struct vertex_struct
{
 float position[3];
 float normal[3];
 float uvmap[2];
} vertex;` so it think it's ok.. tc is texture coordinate and it's two dimensional..

Comment: Actually you were right, this part is mostly code of my colegue so I missed it.. Thank you :) But anyway.. artifacts are still the same..

Comment: @Vallentin: That is an easy mistake to make, but as of late the NDK (the parts of Android that are exposed to languages such as C and C++) actually includes enough of OpenGL and EGL (NDK r5+) to fully implement an OpenGL ES application in C++ on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `GLuint` for some things, but where it really matters you are matching `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` with your C compiler's intrinsic `unsigned short`? `GLushort` is the proper typedef to use, the majority of the time `GLushort` will probably be `unsigned short`, but if there were ever a time where this typedef was not the same it would definitely be on an embedded platform.

Also, do not cast the result of **`offsetof`** to `(void *)`. `size_t` (which the **`offsetof`** macro uses) does not have to be the same size as your platform's native data pointer type (if anything, it will be less than or equal to the pointer size). Consider `(GLubyte *)NULL + offsetof (...)` instead. Using a `size_t` value in pointer arithmetic is safe, but casting `size_t` to a pointer is not.

Neither one of these things is likely to fix your problem, but they are portability issues that you should avoid. The ***real problem*** is almost certainly related to overrunning your element array. GL can use indices that are out-of-range without crashing, in fact outside of WebGL most OpenGL and OpenGL ES implementations do not even define any common behavior for out-of-range buffer access.

I would like to know how `VBOSize` is defined, as this is most likely the culprit.

#### Update:

You are using the wrong size in your call to `glDrawElements (...)` it should be the number of elements in your Index Buffer (`EBOSize` you have called it). Thus,     `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, EBOSize/sizeof(GLushort), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);` *should* fix your problem.

Comment: I have edited original question to address issues metioned (did not fixed the problem as you said) and added code related to VBOSize..

Comment: @BrunoKremel: Try replacing `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, VBOSize/sizeof(GLushort), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);` with this: `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, EBOSize/sizeof(GLushort), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);`

Comment: Thank you very much..  It's actually as I mentioned before my colegue's code and I have deciced to fix it to get it working on my nexus and it's really easy to miss these errors when you are not really into OpenGL ... :)